# application not exiting when using at-at library in clojure

Tags: multithreading, clojure

I am using at-at library and after executing single task, i.e.

```
(at-at/after 5000 #(println "hello from the past!") my-pool)
```

my application doesn't exit. Is it OK that I am executing

```
(System/exit 0)
```

in the end of my application? It's the only way to close the application so far.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `at-at` uses a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), which uses a thread pool of non-daemon threads. The JVM will not exit until all non-daemon threads have exited. `at-at` provides a function `stop-and-reset-pool!` which can be used to stop the pool either gracefully (when work completes) or immediately, which should allow the JVM to exit.

It's also ok to use `System/exit` if you just want to force shutdown (but note that your job will not actually be completed).

Comment: I have tried `stop-and-reset-pool!` and it didn't change anything. Looks like I'll just use `System/exit`